# How do I properly loop through the array to get the index & value so I can edit it?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, search

So I am working on this assignment, i'm sure you've seen it around.
It's basically a list witha  bunch of arrays in it and this is what I did.

I declared this at the top of my class

```
    static List<string[]> logBook = new List<string[]>();
    static string[] post = new string[2];
```

And then I created a function / method that takes a user unput and adds it as a entry.

```
    private static void addToArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: ");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string userInput = dt + " " + Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Message: ");
        string userInputt = "\n\t\t" + Console.ReadLine();

        post = new string[2];
        post[0] = userInput;
        post[1] = userInputt;
        logBook.Add(post);
    }
```

Now what I need to do is to create a function that searches for an entry and then I should be able to edit / remove it if I want to and this is what I was thinking of doing, somethign along these lines.

```
private static void searchArray()
        {
             post.Where(x => x.Contains("someString"));
            for(int i = 0; i < logBook.Length; i++)
              {
                //And then use something here to get the index value of what I found with the .Contains method.
              }
        }
```

Now, i'm having an issue with the search function, I have no idea how tos tructure it? Is my way of thinking even correct here?
How would I properly search for an item and get the index value with it?

Comment: But `post.Where(x => x.Contains("someString"));` will not do anything...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would change "someString" to a userInput, and that would hold the value of Console.ReadLine(); so.. string userInput = Console.ReadLine(); or am I thinking wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that first of all you should change your used datastructure, so you would end up with something like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> logBook = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> ();

private static void addToArray()
{
    var post = new Tuple<string, string>(userInput, userInputt);
    logBook.Add(userInput, post);
    logBook.Add(userInputt, post);
}
```

Then you can easilly search in O(1) time:

```
private static void search()
{
    var key = "your key here";
    if(logBook.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        var post = logBook[key]
        // edit here
        post.Item1 = ....
        post.Item2 = ....
    }
}
```

This solution doesn't handle duplicate input, modify properly if needed.

Comment: The thing is that I have to make use of List<type[]> and I also need a binary search + a bubble sort.

Comment: Sorry it's not obvious what you really want. Why do you need to use a List? Why do you need  to use a binary search when dictionary/hashtable is more efficient?

Comment: School assignment, the logbook should be a list and every entry should be an array, I should implement a binary search method to find and extract entries from the logbook, I should be able to edit, add and remove entries.

Comment: This is really strange, you should edit your post and specify your assignment properly.

Answer (score 0):

create a condition where (ex.) `then` makes removing and `else` makes adjusting. Adjusting can be made by searching,copying, removing the original, editing the copy and insert the later.